# Clojure :: test list for duplicate elements

Tags: clojure

What would be an idiomatic way in Clojure to implement **duplicates?** below:

```
(duplicates? '( 1 2 3 2)) ; true
```

doing a:

```
(not (= (count coll) (count (distinct coll)))
```

is more work than's been asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `distinct?` already exists in clojure.core, so you could use that:

```
user=> (not (distinct? 1 2 3 2))
true
user=> (not (distinct? 1 2 3 4))
false
```

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Nah, not silly - none of us can be expected to know or remember all of the APIs all of the time. I tend to check the Clojure Cheat Sheet regularly, though. http://clojure.org/cheatsheet  :-)